# Using the results from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

Give this set of rules:

```
ToRules[Reduce[a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && a*b == 2*6, {a, b, c}, Rationals]]
```

How do I then use that result? (I'd like to get a list of solutions for that equation.)

I've tried

```
{a, b, c} /. {%}
```

as that has worked with other equations.

But it spits out an error:
[image]

Comment: You can see that `ToRules` is failing to convert. It could be because there's no single unique rule set from that reduction?

Comment: Try `Solve` instead of `Reduce`.

Comment: `Solve[eqns, {a, b, c}, Rationals] //
 
 FullSimplify[#, Element[{a, b, c}, Rationals]] &`

Comment: No, none of that solves the issue. Thanks, though.

Comment: `r = Reduce[a^2 + b^2 == c^2 && a*b == 2*6, {a, b, c}, Rationals] // FullSimplify; {a, b, c} /. Solve[r[[2 ;;]]]`, so we take only "valuable" parts of `Reduce` output and we need to `Solve` instead of `ToRules` because of specific output of `Reduce`.

Comment: Although a bit cryptic, that works. Thanks.